# writing colored output into CSV file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, export-to-csv

I have a program to write content into a CSV file using CSV module in Python. My requirement is to show text in color if a given condition is satisfied. Does anyone has pointers on how to achieve this using CSV module?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!
MSH.

Comment: A csv file does not have color formatting. You must be thinking about csv files opened with Excel. When you open a CSV file in Excel, it's just a plain text file and the coloring is actually done by Excel. Bottom line is: work with excel files and excel packages for python.

Comment: Can you please share a starting file whose content you're looking to transfer to an Excel file?

Comment: @Abdou : Sad to know that CSV doesn't support that. I can try using excel package. Here is the sample content that i'm writing into csv :{"1":["xyz",""],"2":["abc","def"],"3":["zzz",""]}. Keys are headers and values are contents.
say i want to highlight text "xyz" in red based on some condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use an excel file for this, because csv files are merely plain text files that cannot keep any coloring formatting within them. Basically, the only time a CSV file may seem like it's got formatting is when it's opened in Excel.

In any case, my recommendation is that you try using the [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) package for this. You can install it with an easy `pip install XlsxWriter`.

I have created a sample script for you to get you started. You will notice that I have a line that creates a formatting: ***bold*** with `font-size` *red*. That formatting is only used when a cell value (`cell_data`) is equal to `"xyz"`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import xlsxwriter


data = {"1":["xyz",""],"2":["abc","def"],"3":["zzz",""]}

# Use an OrderedDict to maintain the order of the columns
data = OrderedDict((k,data.get(k)) for k in sorted(data.keys()))

# Open an Excel workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('dict_to_excel.xlsx')

# Set up a format
book_format = workbook.add_format(properties={'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})

# Create a sheet
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('dict_data')

# Write the headers
for col_num, header in enumerate(data.keys()):
    worksheet.write(0,col_num, int(header))

# Save the data from the OrderedDict into the excel sheet
for row_num,row_data in enumerate(zip(*data.values())):
    for col_num, cell_data in enumerate(row_data):
        if cell_data ==  "xyz":
            worksheet.write(row_num+1, col_num, cell_data, book_format)
        else:
            worksheet.write(row_num+1, col_num, cell_data)

# Close the workbook
workbook.close()
```

You should get:

[image]

I hope this helps.