# Coloring dataframe before saving

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwt

I have created a df where the values are *"Yes", "No" *and* "Maybe".*

I would like to make this cells colorful before saving in excel. If I use the library **xlwt**, I have something like this:

```
sheet2.write(row, col, str('Allowed'), style)
```

However, I don't want to open the excel again, which it is already created with pandas in order to go through and fill it with my colors. I would like to save my dataframe already with the desired colors formatted in excel.

My dataframe is something like this:

[image]

My desired output is:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249929/writing-colored-output-into-csv-file-in-python

Comment: I want to do this with dataframe already so I don't have to open again with this other library

Comment: check the answer and apply the function in your existing df. It should work as intended. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
def color_df(val): 
    if val == 'Yes':
        color = 'red'
    elif val == 'Maybe':
        color = 'Orange'
    else:
        color = 'Blue'
    return 'color: %s' % color

df = df.style.applymap(color_df).to_excel(path_var + 'styled.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you!

Comment: Pleasure. :) all the best..!!